# I need to write a C++ program that shows the sum of 1 to n for every n from 1 to 50

Tags: c++

I used the below code, but my numbers are incorrect & my instructor would rather I use a for loop. It also needs to print out:

The sum of "n" through "n" is " " (The sum of 1 through 1 is 1)
The sum of "n" through "n" is " " (The sum of 1 through 2 is 3)

I've tried using for loops, but can't seem to get the code right to print out the above. I'm lost!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int NUM_LOOPS = 50;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < NUM_LOOPS)
    {
        cout << "Sum of 1 through " << count << " is " << (count * (++count)) / 2 << endl;
    }

    system("pause.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(count * (++count)) / 2` ? use `sum = 0` variable do `sum += count++;`

Comment: What is the problem with using a for loop for that?

Comment: Well then tell your instructor to come up with a problem that requires a for loop...

Answer (score 7):

With a for loop it looks like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_LOOPS; i++)
{
    cout << "Sum of 1 through " << i << " is " << i*(i+1)/2 << endl;
}
```

You could write it in a `while` loop just as easily if you wished.

Your problem was that you were initialising `count` to `0` rather than `1`. Presumably to deal with the fact that you modified `count` in the middle of the long `cout`. The evaluation of the `<<` operators are unsequenced relative to each other and your code exhibits undefined behaviour, as has been discussed here so many times before.

The bottom line with this is that the pre and post increment operators are dangerous in anything beyond the most simple expressions. Use the sparingly.

Comment: Thank you for the help and advice! I'm still trying to figure all of this stuff out :)

Comment: `<= NUM_LOOPS`, not `<`, so that you also print a line for 50.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int count = 1; count <= NUM_LOOPS; ++count)
{
    cout << "Sum of 1 through " << count << " is " 
         << (count * (count+1)) / 2 << endl;
}
```

Don't do mix funny increments with mathematical formulas. Your future life will be happier.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first programming class ever. I love it, but it's so much different than what I went to school for!

Comment: OP needs the sum of `1..n`, not `0..(n-1)`. When you need inclusive bounds, use `for (int i = first; i <= last; ++i)`. Don't get too much into the habit of using inclusive ranges - see [Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) - but don't fight them when that's what you have.

Comment: It seems you fixed it before I posted the comment anyway - oh well.

Comment: @Steve Thank you, yes, I realised before I read your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good way to calculate every summary. You just need to maintain one summary currently, and each time just add new value

Since multiple operation will cost more time than a single add.

```
const int NUM_LOOPS = 50;
int count = 0, sum = 0;

while ( count < NUM_LOOPS )
  cout << "Sum of 1 through " << count << " is " << (sum+=(++count)) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

My example is from 1 to 10

```
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
             cout << j;
             sum=sum+j;
            if(j != i){
                  cout << " + ";                     
            }
        }
        cout << " = " << sum;  
        sum=0;
       cout <<"\n";
    }
```

Output is:

1 = 1

1 + 2 = 3

1 + 2 + 3 = 6

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 45

1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55